# how to extends a parent property but using a get/set

Tags: typescript

I have a generic class A:

```
class A<T> {
   value: T
}
```

I would like to extend this class the following way:

```
class B extends A<string> {
  get value(): string {
    return this.pValue;
  }
  set value(newValue: string) {
    if (newValue !== this.pValue) {
      this.pValue = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

but it is not possible even though value is a string as I have:

> Property 'value' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TS2611: 'foo' is defined as a property in class 'A', but is overridden here in 'B' as an accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750710/ts2611-foo-is-defined-as-a-property-in-class-a-but-is-overridden-here-in)

Comment: no as the solution `// @ts-nocheck` is not really a solution. is there no other way ?>

Comment: That's not the only answer, and your just not liking the solutions doesn't make it not a dupe.